# how to return unique pairs in a list (with different order) in same object in python

Tags: python, unique

how can I get the unique pairs in the table?

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | One | B |
| A | One | B |
| B | One | A |
| C | One | D |
| E | One | F |

I want to get the unique pairs of column 1 and 3, and return value like
{'A&B','C&D','E&F'}

Comment: If you want to treat `A&B` and `B&A` as identical, you can construct both `Col1 & Col3` and `Col3 & Col1` then take the minimum

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 1):

Try with `unique`:

```
>>> (df['Col 1'] + '&' + df['Col 3']).unique()
array(['A&B', 'B&A', 'C&D', 'E&F'], dtype=object)
>>>
```

Or `drop_duplicates`:

```
>>> (df['Col 1'] + '&' + df['Col 3']).drop_duplicates()
0    A&B
2    B&A
3    C&D
4    E&F
dtype: object
>>>
```

---

If you treat `A&B` identical to `B&A`, try:

```
>>> df[['Col 1', 'Col 3']].agg(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand').agg('&'.join, axis=1).unique()
array(['A&B', 'C&D', 'E&F'], dtype=object)
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> df[['Col 1', 'Col 3']].agg(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand').agg('&'.join, axis=1).drop_duplicates()
0    A&B
3    C&D
4    E&F
dtype: object
>>>
```

Comment: thanks. if I only want to get the pairs appear more than once, how should I adjust ?

Comment: @ETT Maybe try `df['Col 1'] + '&' + df['Col 3']`.

Comment: like this? df[[df['Col 1'] + '&' + df['Col 3']]].agg(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand').agg('&'.join, axis=1).drop_duplicates()

Comment: @ETT Yes! That would work

Comment: Nothing against your answer @ U12-Forward but this confusion could have been avoided by supplying a coded attempt or expected output @ETT.. Please use this comment as guidance for the future.

Comment: it gets error....

Comment: @ETT What's the error ??

Comment: Maybe try importing pandas?

Comment: None of [Index(['XXXX...(objects in my table)'],\n      dtype='object', length=12382)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @ETT That's not an error produced in my code... So please try this on this dataframe, if it works, please accept this answer and upvote it.

Comment: I use this code to the df: df[[df['col_1'] + '&' + df['col_3']]].agg(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand').agg('&'.join, axis=1).drop_duplicates() ...............and still get error KeyError: "None of [Index([('A&B', 'A&B', 'B&A', 'C&D')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @ETT Use: `(df['col_1'] + '&' + df['col_2']).agg(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand').agg('&'.join, axis=1).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Still get error:::::: ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series

Comment: @ETT `df[['Col 1', 'Col 3']].agg(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand').agg('&'.join, axis=1).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: @ETT Does that work??

Comment: its works but it does not return the pairs appear more than once

Comment: @ETT Then just simply only use `(df['Col 1'] + '&' + df['Col 3'])`

Comment: @ETT You're asking a new question here, please accept my answer by clicking ✔️ and ask a new question